# Spring boot - Post function get error while Get and Delete function still be ok

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm newly get to spring framework and handing-on basic steps however I got a error which didn't where it come from. I just use **Postman** to communicate with data. Get and delete function were smooth, however Post and Put didn't.
This is my code:

Class ***EmployeeRepo***

```
package com.employee.demo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.employee.demo.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>{

}
```

Class ***Employee***

```
package com.employee.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee with [ID: " + id + ", name: " + name + " and salary: " + salary + "]";
    }
}
```

Class ***EmployeeController***

```
package com.employee.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.employee.demo.dao.EmployeeRepo;
import com.employee.demo.model.Employee;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo repo;
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public String  deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
        Employee empl = repo.getOne(id);
        repo.delete(empl);
        return "deleted";
    }

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public Employee addEmployee(Employee empl) {
        repo.save(empl);
        return empl;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/employee", consumes = {"application/json"})
    public Employee saveOrUpdateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee empl) {
        repo.save(empl);
        return empl;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public Optional<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
        return repo.findById(id);
    }
}
```

And this is what I got from postman for Post query
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You're missing the @RequestBody annotation in your POST method.

Comment: @GauravDhiman as what you see from the image, my input and output data are different. My output should be: id:127, name: Joshep, salary: 3550. But in fact, it return 0 and null

Comment: @PradiptaSarma thanks bro, I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your POST method (addEmployee)- Whatever you are sending in request body is not accepted by addEmployee method. You can verify in DB after a POST call.

employee table will have data something like [image: blank data inserted]

Use @RequestBody annotation with argument as:

```
public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee empl)
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I fixed it